# Hiding Registry Keys

Tags: registry, key, hidden

Is there any way you can hide a registry key/value in Windows programmatically? I am NOT developing any sort of malware, I just think that it would be cool to be able to do this. I may even need to use this technique in the future to use for licensing my software that I develop. I read about using `\0` in the name but this didn't work for me, the key couldn't be created with a `\` in it and the values weren't hidden. I searched through Google and SO but couldn't find anything relevant. Has anyone managed to do this? I would prefer to do this in C# but if not which language could I use? Thanks.